# MVC 4 Update Menu On Every View Load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared view _layout.cshtml that will contain the number of unread messages for the user. We need to check for new messages every time the user visits a new view. At this time, I don't see the need to do this on a timed ajax-type call.

I can do this all day with Master Pages on .NET Webforms but I'm having a hard time doing something this simple with MVC.

My question is: how can I trigger a database call on every view load to check and see if there is a change in the number of messages and update the text in the _layout.cshtml?

Comment: you could pass the data in your model or make a jquery call on $ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a partial view which will contain your unread messages etc
2. Create a model to pass to the view
3. Create a "Partial Action"
4. From your _Layout, call `Html.RenderAction` (or `Html.Action()`)

We prefix partials with an underscore.

**Views\Shared\_UnreadMessagesPartial.cshtml**

```
@model UnreadMessagesViewModel

Unread messages: @Model.UnreadMessagesCount
```

**UnreadMessagesViewModel.cs**

```
public class UnreadMessagesViewModel
{
    private DbContext _db;

    public int UnreadMessagesCount;

    public UnreadMessagesViewModel() {
        _db = new DbContext();
        UnreadMessages = _db.Messages.Count();
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // mark this action as unavailable to the general public
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult _UnreadMessagesPartial()
    {
        UnreadMessagesViewModel viewModel = new UnreadMessagesViewModel();
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
}
```

**Views\Shared\_Layout.cs**

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("_UnreadMessagesPartial");
}
```

I hope my C# is ok, had to convert from VB.NET in my head.